# Need help getting Ninject equivalent for StructureMap syntax

Tags: c#, ioc-container, structuremap, ninject, ravendb

I am trying to implement IoC (Ninject) for Ravendb and have ran into a little snag.  I am using code from http://www.dotnetguy.co.uk/post/2010/06/12/raven-db-ndash-part-1-ndash-documentsession-per-request-with-structuremap to help.

```
public interface IRavenSessionFactoryBuilder
{
    IRavenSessionFactory GetSessionFactory();
}

public class RavenSessionFactoryBuilder : IRavenSessionFactoryBuilder
{
    private IRavenSessionFactory _ravenSessionFactory;

    public IRavenSessionFactory GetSessionFactory()
    {
        return _ravenSessionFactory ?? (_ravenSessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory());
    }

    private static IRavenSessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        Debug.Write("IRavenSessionFactory Created");
        return new RavenSessionFactory(new DocumentStore
                                           {
                                               Url =
                                                   System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[
                                                       "Raven.DocumentStore"]
                                           });
    }
}

public interface IRavenSessionFactory
{
    IDocumentSession CreateSession();
}

public class RavenSessionFactory : IRavenSessionFactory
{
    private readonly IDocumentStore _documentStore;

    public RavenSessionFactory(IDocumentStore documentStore)
    {
        if (_documentStore != null) return;
        _documentStore = documentStore;
        _documentStore.Initialize();
    }

    public IDocumentSession CreateSession()
    {
        Debug.Write("IDocumentSession Created");
        return _documentStore.OpenSession();
    }
}
```

I am unsure how to convert the following structure map syntax.

```
ObjectFactory.Configure(x => x.For<IDocumentSession>()
                  .HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
                  .AddInstances(inst => inst.ConstructedBy
                    (context => context.GetInstance<IRavenSessionFactoryBuilder>()
                      .GetSessionFactory().CreateSession())));
```

In My attempt, _ravenSessionFactory is null on every request because of the new constructor.

```
Bind<IDocumentSession>().ToMethod(
            x => new RavenSessionFactoryBuilder().GetSessionFactory().CreateSession()).RequestScope();
```

Thanks for anyone taking the time to try and help explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `new RavenSessionFactoryBuilder().GetSessionFactory()....`, I would think you'd want:

```
Kernel.Get<IRavenSessionFactoryBuilder>().GetSessionFactory()....
```

where you've done something like this beforehand:

```
Bind<IRavenSessionFactoryBuilder>().To<IRavenSessionFactoryBuilder>()
  .InSingletonScope();
```

Disclaimer: I've never tried a `Get` in a `Bind` statement before. You might need a factory method.

Comment: I got rid of my line and added the 2 lines that you mentioned.  I now get an error "Error activating IDocumentSession.  No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable. ...."

Comment: That just means that you need to add a binding for `IDocumentSession`, like `Bind<IDocumentSession>().To<DocumentSession>();` You're a step closer.

Comment: I am definitely getting closer now.  I have the same error with IDatabaseCommands.  Nothing seems to want to bind with it.  http://pastebin.com/U2qyf51m

Comment: I don't know anything about RavenDB. However, in doing some reading and looking at the above, the `IDocumentSession` should be bound to `ravenSessionFactory.CreateSession()` using `ToMethod`. That should bypass the need to bind `IDatabaseCommands`.

Comment: I've done a little more research. Assuming you're running in MVC, I think you just want `Bind<IDocumentSession>().ToMethod(context => context.GetInstance<IRavenSessionFactoryBuilder>().GetSessionFactory().CreateSession());`

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I want to do from doing some research myself.  The only problem now is that Ninject does not have a GetInstance method.

Comment: Got it to work...I am using Bind<IDocumentSession>().ToMethod(context => Kernel.Get<IRavenSessionFactoryBuilder>().GetSessionFactory().CreateSession());

Answer (score 13):

Factories are called providers in Ninject. Convert the `SessionFactory` to a `SessionProvider`:-

```
public class RavenSessionProvider : Provider<IDocumentSession>
{
    private readonly IDocumentStore _documentStore;

    public RavenSessionFactory(IDocumentStore documentStore)
    {
        _documentStore = documentStore;
    }

    public IDocumentSession GetInstance(IContext ctx)
    {
        Debug.Write("IDocumentSession Created");
        return _documentStore.OpenSession();
    }
}
```

Also change your RavenSessionFactoryBuilder to a DocumentStoreProvider:-

```
public class DocumentStoreProvider : Provider<IDocumentStore>
{
    public IDocumentStore GetInstance(IContext ctx)
    {
        var store = new DocumentStore 
                   { Url = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Raven.DocumentStore"]});
        store.Initialize();
        return store;
    }
}
```

And add bindings:

```
Bind<RavenSessionProvider>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope()
Bind<IDocumentSession>().ToProvider<RavenSessionProvider>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ninject basically has 5 options for scope.

TransientScope - the one you're using means that a new instance is created for every request

SingletonScope - only one instance is ever created

ThreadScope - only one instance is created per thread

RequestScope - only one instance is created per HttpRequest

Custom - you provide the scope object

If you're creating a web app you can just specify `.InRequestScope()` If it's a windows app you might specify `.InThreadScope()`

Finally if you must specify a hybrid (I'm not totally sure how it works in structure map) you might do `.InScope(ctx => HttpRequest.Current != null ? HttpRequest.Current : Thread.CurrentThread)`

Comment: Thanks.  In my question, I made a mistake and put InTransientScope() instead of RequestScope().  The problem is that _ravenSessionFactory is null on every request because of the new constructor.  SM is using the same instance every time (it appears)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a factory or provider etc to do this.

Ninject does the session per request work for you create a Ninject module that binds a document store in InSingletonScope(), then bind a DocumentSession in Request scope and your ready to go.

I've blogged a step by step guide for Ninject and RavenDB

http://www.dalsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2012/04/12/mvc-get-ravendb-up-and-running-in-5-minutes-using-ninject/